# Getting empty array in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.8

I'm getting empty array when i try to run the code below. How can i fix this?

```
import pandas as pd 
import os 
import time 
from datetime import datetime

path = "C:/Users/Tuna/Desktop/sk/intraQuarter"

def Key_Stats(gather="Total Debt/Equity (mrq)"):
    statspath = path+'/_KeyStats'
    stock_list = [x[0] for x in os.walk(statspath)]
    print(stock_list)
    

Key_Stats()
```

Comment: Windows paths use backslashes, no?

Comment: Either slashes are valid separators in python on windows.

Comment: Print `os.path.abspath(statspath)` and confirm there are files in the folder. Not nice using the global `path` - much better to pass this as a parameter into the function. And `gather` isn’t used in the function - why is it there?

Answer (score 0):

Do some testing with different things and maybe you'll see that what os.walk() isn't doint what you think it is.

```
path = "C:/Users/Tuna/Desktop/sk/intraQuarter"

def Key_Stats(gather="Total Debt/Equity (mrq)"):
    statspath = path+'/_KeyStats'
    # print(list(os.walk(statspath)))
    for x in os.walk(statspath):
        print(x)
    # stock_list = [x[0] for x in os.walk(statspath)]
    # print(stock_list)
    

Key_Stats()
```

The list comprehension x[0] only gave me my statspath. The following gave me the list of files. First had to make a list from the generator, then take the 3rd element.

```
path = "C:/Users/Tuna/Desktop/sk/intraQuarter"

def Key_Stats(gather="Total Debt/Equity (mrq)"):
    statspath = path+'/_KeyStats'
    stock_list = list(os.walk(statspath))[0][2]
    # print(stock_list)
    

Key_Stats()
```